# View ignores unchecked "require this relationship"

Tags: 8, views

I am building a view in Drupal 8 that calls for two relationships:

- Nodes referenced by the current node (relationship required)
- A single node referenced by the above reference node (relationship not required)

Although that second relationship isn't required, my view is still filtering out all nodes where that second relationship is null. Is anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by changing which field I wanted from the reference node. I was originally trying to get the path, but I switched it to "Link to Content." Still, it's odd that when trying to get just the path, views suddenly requires the relationship.